# GXT3 HtmlEditor.setEnabled() causes exception if invoked before the component is displeyed

Tags: java, gwt, extjs, gxt

I use GWT2.5 with GXT 3.0.1 UI library.
The application works in Development Mode while shows empty screen when compiled.
The first simple loading GXT screen shows for a moment and then the webpage goes blank.

In many cases there are problems with:

```
validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar
validation-api-1.0.0.GA-sources.jar
```

Those are added.

GXT inherit looks like this:

```
<inherits name='com.sencha.gxt.ui.GXT' />
```

Can't really think of anything else...

---

---- UPDATE ----

I narrowed down the problem. Page content disappears because I create a dialog during construction of the panel. I moved dialog creation to lazy initialization. I see the contents, but dialog doesn't display upon dialog.show() method.

Something's wrong with the GXT Dialog implementation I guess.

Comment: Are you certain that when not running it in dev mode that you have performed and deployed a GWT-compile?  A blank screen in my experience is usually the result of not doing the compile, or in my Eclipse environment, having the GWT compile Advanced settings pointing to the wrong location for my server.

Comment: By removing components from my application I found that the problem lies in one of the GXT components. I haven't nailed it down to a particular one just yet as it requires recompiling every time. One thing is certain though. It has nothing to do with compilation process itself as if enough components get removed the page starts showing its remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I nailed it.
Dialog contains HtmlEditor, which performed setEnabled(false) on. The call fails in compiled version, while works fine in dev.

Clearly a bug. Call to setEnabled() in show() method or any other method after it's been displayed seems to fail also. So it's just a bug somewhere in the method itself.

More details in Sencha premium support forum for those with access:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259570-GXT-3.0.1-application-goes-blank-when-compiled&p=951171#post951171

Comment: Have you tried with a newer version? If you have access to premium forums, then you also have access to the latest support release, 3.0.4.

Comment: I have access, but I haven't tried their latest. My past experience with Sencha shows that bugs like that don't get fixed for years, so I don't expect this to be fixed any time soon. All I need is workarounds.

Comment: As a developer who works on GXT, I'll note that you haven't provided a test case, just a quick text description of what you did and a compiled stack trace that can't be converted into Java. No bricks == no clay ;).

Comment: As a GXT developer you can see multiple bug reports from me on the premium forum. ;)

Comment: Particularly, about live grid view infinite loop, where I provided test case that reproduces the bug in 100% cases for all 2.x.x versions. http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?135660-Infinite-loop-when-using-LiveGridView-with-a-small-cache It's been almost 2 years since my bug report, so my expectations are pretty low. ;)

Comment: Yep - we've resolved the livegrid one in 3.x, but the code is different in 2, and it hasn't been properly backported. I'm actually referring to this specific case - but feel free to email me at colin.alworth@sencha.com if you want to discuss more issues unrelated to this one, or you can always open a support ticket. I'll check out the other issues on your name I can in the next day or so.

Comment: Thank you! I saved your contact. Currently I have workarounds for all reported bugs except live grid view. And one missing feature is much desired: editable live grid view. I made editable live grid myself, but its selection model works unreliably. I found combination of indices that works in most of the cases, but it still doesn't work reliably. Especially, if it's multiple selection. Otherwise, you're not too far from such a great addition to your grid family.

Comment: Lets pick this up in email (or IRC!), but editable live grid has a whole host of application specific... nastiness. We deliberatly don't implement that, but leave it to teams to build in the specific way they want. We could consider a sample demonstrating it, but I hate the implication of the One True Way when there are many. Selection model has the same issue, since you could in theory select every item you see, even when many of those are paged out of memory...